# SQL export data

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, databaselink, sql

I have data imported from excel file into mathematica but mathematica automatically converts large number into scientific form and when transferring this data to sql string field i get the following ...e+... nonsense.

1.00001e+006

I tried using `$PrePrint=NumberForm[#,ExponentFunction->(Null&)]&` which fixes the problem when working in mathematica but data going into sql still contains e. Please help i need to get this fixed on an urgent basis.

Is there a way to tell mathematica to never use e or any exponentiation internally as well?

Comment: If I remember correctly from when I used ``"DatabaseLink`"`` you can pass a string to a string field. Is that right? If so try pre-generating your strings (i.e. with `ToString`).

Comment: I am importing from excel using `ExcelLink` package. So for example i have a number 234234822342351. coming from Excel (Excel internally keeps all numbers as floating point even those appearing as integer). If i apply `ToString[234234822342351.]` i don't get integer. So the question is can mathematica determine if a number is integer by looking at decimal digits?

Comment: Definitely doable via multiple methods. Try `Round[intList, 10^-17]` or searching on this site.

Comment: It sounds as if you are converting numbers to strings to insert into a SQL database. You don't need to do that. May you include a bit of code where you are inserting the value into the database. There is a more robust method of inserting into SQL.